# Can I add object files as dependency?

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I have a makefile for multiple mains

```
info ::
        @echo "make main1/2/3"

PROGS = main1 main2 main3

.SECONDEXPANSION:
${PROGS} :: $$@.o
        ${CC} -o $@ $^
```

but one (and only one) main needs another object linked in. I tried solving that with

```
main3 :: lib.o
```

but somehow `lib.o` is not added to the list of prerequisites.

The ordering of the link lines makes a difference.

- I add that `main3` line after the `PROGS` link line, then that one bombs because of the missing object file.
- If I add it *before* the `PROGS` line, then the custom line is executed first with a default rule, which I don't want, and then the `PROGS` rule is executed anyway, and it bombs.

Is there a way to use macros such as `$^` for objects linking? I can of course split out main3 from the `PROGS` macro, but that macro is used for a bunch of other purposes too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using double-colon rules in a case which doesn't seem to call for them. From [the manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Double_002dColon):

> Double-colon rules with the same target are in fact completely separate from one another. Each double-colon rule is processed individually, just as rules with different targets are processed.

If you want different rules for the same target to *combine* (as you seem to want for `main3`), just switch to ordinary (single-colon) rules:

```
.SECONDEXPANSION:
${PROGS} : $$@.o
    ${CC} -o $@ $^

main3 : lib.o
```

And you can make your `${PROGS}` rule less complicated by turning it into a [static pattern rule](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Static-Pattern):

```
${PROGS} : % : %.o
    ${CC} -o $@ $^
```

Comment: You're right, I should have just used single colons. They do have their purpose, but this is not one of those.